# Does an Array List have a default sort?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, asna-visual-rpg

I have a WCF service to return customer data.  An arraylist is created by adding a new instance of an object.  The code looks like this:

```
objCust.CUSTNUM  = CustomerByNumber_CST#9A
objCust.CUSTNAME = CustomerByNumber_NAME9A
objCust.CUSTADR1 = CustomerByNumber_ADR19A
objCust.CUSTADR2 = CustomerByNumber_ADR29A
objCust.CUSTCITY = CustomerByNumber_CITY9A
objCust.CUSTSTAT = CustomerByNumber_STAT9A
objCust.CUSTZIP  = CustomerByNumber_ZIPC9A
objCust.CUSTPHON = CustomerByNumber_PHON9A

aryList.Add(objCust)
```

I then return the array list as an array - aryList.ToArray(...

When I call the service, the array elements come back sorted in alphabetical order - here is the output:

```
<b:CUSTADR1>3910 LAKEFIELD DR</b:CUSTADR1>
<b:CUSTADR2>JOHNS CREEK FACILITY</b:CUSTADR2>
<b:CUSTCITY>SUWANEE</b:CUSTCITY>
<b:CUSTNAME>JOHNSON CONTROLS</b:CUSTNAME>
<b:CUSTNUM>1688</b:CUSTNUM>
<b:CUSTPHON>770-495-9950</b:CUSTPHON>
<b:CUSTSTAT>GA</b:CUSTSTAT>
<b:CUSTZIP>30024</b:CUSTZIP>
```

I'm not doing any sorting.  Why is this sorted?  I'd like it to be in the order that I added them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF data contract serializers sort **object** properties unless you provide a specific order numeric value in the `DataMemberAttribute` declaration. It has nothing to do with arrays and would happen even if you return a single object.